# How to fix Inbuilt Cheese (webcam) app in the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: cheese, 22.04

On upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS from 20.04 LTS, the inbuilt cheese application is not working properly. On running it, displays a Blank Black Screen.
[image]

Unable to capture vedios also. It gets stucked.

Please help me in fixing this.

Comment: actually before doing that
Try lowering the settings
like the photo and video resolution
It might solve your problem

Comment: Having the same issue, but also with other apps. Video driver issue in the new kernel perhaps?

Comment: Same issue here in Ubuntu 22.04. Try to launch cheese in terminal. Took a photo and here is the error : ```(cheese:16465): cheese-WARNING **: 21:52:05.432: Output state was not configured: ../gst-libs/gst/video/gstvideoencoder.c(2281): gst_video_encoder_can_push_unlocked (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstEncodeBin:image-encodebin/GstJpegEnc:jpegenc0``` When I launch Cheese with sudo. It works !
But the picture is saved in /root/.gnome2/cheese I'm not sure to understand, and less sure how to fix it !

Answer (score 3):

Check preferences then change the device webcam. That fixed issue on my side.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6tiv.png)

Answer (score 2):

Just a couple of suggestions It may or may not work:

**First:** Try lowering the settings like the photo and video resolution It might solve your problem.
OR, try to increase the image/video resolution : this solved the problem in my case ( DELL Latitude E6130)

**Second:** have you install codecs yet? if not, just run

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

**Third:** If it still doesn't work
try installing kamoso. as an alternative camera app

```bash
sudo apt install kamoso
```

Comment: For me the problem was the shutter was closed. 
Please see this: https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-in/inspiron-14-5410-2-in-1-laptop/inspiron-5410-2-in-1-setup-and-specifications/using-the-privacy-shutter?guid=guid-514df42a-261e-493a-9ddb-08f3d2e3b8ab&lang=en-us

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems with cheese crashing on a fresh install of ubuntu 22.04 and discovered at ubuntu software center that there is a snap store's cheese. Removed the distribution one and tried the snap store one and it worked